# Safari compatibility issue with drop shadow in SVG foreignObject

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, foreignobject

When using a `dropshadow` on an element within a `foreignObject` in a SVG, this element does not display at the right position and scale on Safari while it is working properly on Chrome and Safari.

Here is my SVG code :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 375 666">
  <!-- ... -->
  <g transform="translate(186.7810034751892, 0)">
    <foreignObject y="0" width="145" height="62">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">
          <span>Some text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
  <!-- ... -->
</svg>
```

and my CSS code :

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.element {
  min-height: 24px;
  max-width: 130px;
  background-color: #C4E7EE;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #0A99B7;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 4px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4)); /* The problematic drop shadow */
  margin: 12px;
}
```

When removing the drop-shadow, the element is placed at the right position and scale. You can try it on this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/odv3bh9j/

For now, I have found the following workaround by removing the drop shadow :

```css
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
  @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (display:flow-root) {
    .element {
      filter: unset;
    }
  }
}
```

But I am wondering if there is any better solution ?

Comment: foreignObject is a really buggy element FWIW

Comment: It seems to be... But what's the solution then when you need to use them ? Replacing SVG by HTML Canvas ?

Comment: You can use SVG text, although then you have to manually calculate wrapping & spacing which is a pain in the neck, and you have to do a solid job of cross-browser testing because you never know when you're going to run into an SVG text attribute with a bug in some browser. There are libraries to help (like https://github.com/dowjones/svg-text - haven't used it)